# Flutter Firestore: How to check if all document writes completed successfully

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When the device is offline, the app stores any Firestore changes locally and update them when the internet connection is back. Is there a way to check in the app if the local changes finished uploading Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API to get a list of the pending writes, nor is there a flag that signals whether there are pending writes. But there are a few things you can do:

1. For a specific write, you can attach a completion listener to detect when it has completed. When the `Future` that the write resolves, the write has been committed on the server.
2. When you're getting a `DocumentSnapshot`, you can check the [`hasPendingWrites` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/SnapshotMetadata/hasPendingWrites.html) in its metadata to see whether the snapshot has pending changes.

Comment: Wouldn't hasPendingWrites be more informative here?

Comment: Oooh... good one. I somehow forgot about that property. I updated my answer (and thanks for fixing the typo in there too).